# Importing data from txt to Access with non default delimiter

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, import, text-files

I am aware that there is a feature that can do this if the character delimiter is tab, space, ";" or ",".

However the files I'm getting are delimited with ÿ.

Is there a script i can run in vba that does this, and works with ÿ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about simply using a `replace(string, "ÿ", ";")` and have fun?

Comment: can i do this for whole txt files inside vba and then use an import specification?

Comment: Probably. Simply read the file, change it and save it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to once create an Importspecification manually with the Import Text Wizard.
Then you can use it like this:

```
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "Your Specification Name", "Destination Table Name", "File Name", [has Headers]
```

Comment: I've tested this here with Access 2013 and ÿ is accepted but Access does not seem to interpret it correct ;-(

Answer (score 0):

open the text file in notepad. try find and replace feature. in find put `ÿ` and replace it with `;`. your data will be ready to be used with the default import feature afterwards. this way you won't have to fiddle with custom importspecifications etc. I used the same trick to import a rather large file right into access.